# Was this samurai the inspiration for the blind general's character in One Piece?

Tags: one-piece

[This blind guy](https://youtu.be/_Hvc1Ae-YCU?t=3m53s)'s attitude, facial expressions, and facial structure look very specifically like the blind samurai general in One Piece, who can lift mountains with his Devil Fruit powers. They even, from this short scene, have nearly identical personalities.

Did this movie character inspire the One Piece character, or is there no known relation?

Comment: Note: If anyone knows the actual names of these 2 characters, feel free to edit my question, as I know neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blind samurai you're referring to is Zatoichi, and the blind Admiral in One Piece is named Issho, aka Fujitora. And yes, as revealed in SBS Volume 74, Fujitora was inspired by Zatoichi, and particularly his portrayal by Japanese actor Shintaro Katsu. Both swordsmen share quite a few characteristics, such as their blindness, proficiency with a sword, or their love of gambling.